# MITM based on ARP spoofing

Tags: man-in-the-middle, spoofing, detection, arp-spoofing

I fail to understand how a MITM attack sniffs packets and modifies them.In the case of ARP spoofing although the attacker has spoofed the MAC address of a host, how does he modify it? 
if he listen to the message between the sender and destination  and after the message delivered to destination he sent gratuitous ARP reply ? when he know the message  delivered to destination ?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, to perform MITM attack between A & B, you must apply 3 steps:

1. Trick A to think you're B
2. Trick B to think you're A
3. Enable packets forwarding

To answer you question, there are 3 types of ARP packets, the normal send and reply packets, and **gratuitous** packets.

Using gratuitous packets, the attacker can modify or 'poison' the targets cache, so he can trick both A & B, and stay in their ARP table as a legit part of the connection.

Note that this kind of attacks can be stopped using some kind of switches which is able to sniff the network for gratuitous arp packets and re-send the correct data through the network.